# About the function MERGE in Common Lisp

Tags: merge, common-lisp

What is the logic of the function `merge`?

Isn't it that if the judgement returns true, choose the first element in list1, or if false, list2?

I was confused by the following two sentences...

(merge 'list '(1) '(2) #'<)  ==>  (1 2)

(merge 'list '(1) '(2) #'=)  ==>  (1 2)

Why they get the same result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of `merge` contains **all** elements of both sequences.

If the predicate is T then the first element is placed first.

```
CL-USER 57 > (merge 'list
                    (list 1 2)
                    (list 2 1)
                    #'<)
(1 2 2 1)

CL-USER 58 > (merge 'list
                    (list 1 2)
                    (list 2 1)
                    #'=)
(1 2 2 1)

CL-USER 59 > (merge 'list
                    (list 1 2)
                    (list 2 1)
                    #'>)
(2 1 2 1)
```

Basic use case of `merge`: merging two sorted sequences will result into one sorted sequence containing all the elements.

```
CL-USER 63 > (merge 'list
                    '(1 2 6)
                    '(3 4 5)
                    #'<)
(1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

Works with vector, too:

```
CL-USER 64 > (merge 'vector
                    #(1 2 6)
                    #(3 4 5)
                    #'<)
#(1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

Comment: Is the function merge like merge sort?
Is the predicate exerted between the two fist elements in each list?

Comment: @chaosink: The basic use case of `merge` is: merge two sorted lists to create a sorted result list containing all elements of both lists.